# Why not simply use [NSDate date]?

Tags: objective-c, object

Why is the convention to use the nested alloc and init statement to create an instance? Why not just use something like the below? The only time I can think of is if you wanted to use one of the custom init methods - is there any other good reason?

`NSDate *now = [NSDate date];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between \[\[NSDate date\] retain\] and \[\[NSDate alloc\] init\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102706/difference-between-nsdate-date-retain-and-nsdate-alloc-init)

Answer (score 5):

`NSDate *now = [NSDate date];` returns an autoreleased date, it is a "convenience" class method

`NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];` returns a retained date.

Typically `[NSDate date];` is the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for persistence, especially in comparing dates, you need them to last a while. Using the singleton approach `[NSDate date]` you receive an autoreleased object which is unsafe to use out of scope.

Comment: This is not "the singleton approach". In fact, this has nothing to do with singletons.

Comment: `[NSDate date]` does not return a singleton, it is a "connivence" class method.

Comment: @CocoaFu I think you meant *convenience*, not *connivence*.